# An erroroccured while trying to create a file in destination directory

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, installation, filesystems

I am using VS Code in my windows 10 desktop  to develop Reactjs and ReactNative projects. some days before an error dialogue box opened suddenly with following notice

[image: Error while Open VS Code]

I have not been using VS Code for long i fear anything wrong with installation, although everything was working fine. what actually happened here?

Comment: Please try this solution. It solved the same issue for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64219188/3750916

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error, then, I tried to resolve that by updating and reinstalling VS Code, and by deleting the **000unins.exe** file in the destination folder. But the error wasn't resolved. Finally, I resolved that with the following ways:

**1.** When I run VS Code as administrator the error didn't occured.

**2.** I uninstalled VS Code and downloaded VS [Code ZIP](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/?dv=winzip) file instead of the installer and unzipped it in my `AppData\Local\Programs` folder. It's been working fine and the error hasn't occured.