# Getting Select Action error while using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, error-handling, makefile, createfile, vs-extensibility

I am getting the below alert on a certain interval while using VS Code have attached the SS of the same. Using VS for quite sometime but never encountered this issue before. Please help me to resolve the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was in trouble with the same issue recently. You can resolve it by simply granting full access to all users or running the vscode as an administrator. (This question was answered already. You can get more information from [Visual Studio Code - access denied to unins000.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64202257/visual-studio-code-access-denied-to-unins000-exe.))

Comment: If a question was already answered, you should flag it as a duplicate, instead of answering it.